# $state.go('^') in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

What does `$state.go('^');` mean in $stateProvider. I know that

```
$state.go('view_name');
```

lands on particular `view_name`.

Answer (score 2):

This will take you to a parent state..
Follow this [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) for more details.